# Avoiding module groupings with multiple source roots

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Summary:

I want to be able to use "Scroll from Source" to locate a file in the filesystem tree.  For normal modules this works well.  However, when I include an additional source root for some generated code in a module, IntelliJ creates a virtual module in the left pane with a duplicate copy of the sources, and "Scroll from Source" sometimes navigates there instead of in the filesystem tree.

How can I add an additional source root such that it does not result in virtual module entries in the left pane?

More details:

I am using IntelliJ 12.1.3 with an Android project that has several modules.  Most of the IntelliJ modules include two source roots: one for the actual source and one for Android generated sources.  Some of the modules also include source generated by an external tool.  These modules include a third source root.

In the left pane, the modules with the additional source root show up as virtual module entries at the top-level and in the directory tree where the .iml file is found, but the modules with just android generated source just appear in the directory tree.

The virtual module entries cause problems during "Scroll from Source" since IntelliJ sometimes scrolls to the virtual module rather than the source location in the tree.

I experimented with groups, but groups did not solve the issue of the files showing up in two places, and they further obscured the filesystem tree.

Because the Android gen directory does not cause these virtual modules to appear, there must be a way to convince IntelliJ that some source roots are less interesting.  However, in the .iml file, the Android entry and the annotation processing entry look identical aside from referencing different paths.  The android source root value also appears under the android facet as the values for options named GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_APT and GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_AIDL--is the android plugin doing something special here to make its gen folder avoid triggering the virtual module?

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the project panel there is a drop-down that probably says "Project". If you change that to packages you may get what you're looking for.

However, it sounds more like you have a problem with the location of the generated sources. Generally speaking, it isn't a great idea to rely on your IDE to build your project. You're better of using maven and the ([Maven Android Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted). This will allow you to share your code more easily with others (and almost any project worth working on is worth sharing). IntelliJ should pick up the maven project description and 'understand' how to build your project. Now, you want to setup the plugin to generate the code into the 'target' directory, which should exist under your project root, and IntelliJ's project/module configuration should exclude the target directory by default (when the project is imported from a pom). This will ensure that you don't see generated sources in your project structure, but they should still be available for reference by your app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this removes the directory tree from the left pane.  I am actually looking for the opposite: keep the directory tree and remove the virtual entries so I can see source files in the context of where they are in the file system.  Also, totally agree on not building in IDE--I just want IntelliJ to be able to see the generated code so it can support completion, flag typos, etc.